# Unable to inspect PowerShell string[] arrays in Visual Studio 2015 debug watch/locals windows

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, powershell, visual-studio-2015, powershell-5.0

I have the following code:

```
$some_things = "first", "second", "third"

[string[]] $other_things = "first", "seconds", "third"

[int[]] $more_things = 1,2,3,4

Write-Output "Break here"  ## Breakpoint here
```

When debugging the above PowerShell script in Visual Studio 2015 I noticed the following peculiarity. If I examine the three variables from above in a watch window I see the following:

[image]

What's odd is that when I expand `$other_things` I don't see any member elements. I know they are there because I can loop over the array using:

```
Write-Output "Length: $($other_things.Length)"
ForEach($thing in $other_things) {
    Write-Output "Thing: $thing"
}
```

and get the following output in VS's Output window:

[image]

So it seems that if I cast my array variable during assignment to `string[]` VS is unable to expand that array. If I don't cast things work as expected.

Running the same code in PowerGUI (my usual goto PowerShell debug/scripting IDE) doesn't exhibit the same problem:

[image]

*Is this a bug in the Visual Studio 2015 Powershell debugger?*

(Background: the reason this has arisen is that I'm calling a legacy `.asmx` SOAP webservice and one of the service methods returns a `string[]` array just like `$other_things` above which I couldn't inspect. It wasn't until I wrapped the service call in the array sub-expression operator (`@()`), which returned to me a `System.Object[]` array of strings, could I then properly inspect the array contents.)

Comment: This is quite peculiar. That being said, avoid type-casting variables on assigment in PowerShell. Strong typing is *not* PowerShell's strong suit (no pun intended)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen - I agree, and don't have a problem `@()`'ing the webservice call that returns this string typed array, but curiosity etc :)

Comment: Lol...I'll have a read of that answer when I get back from dinner. Also noticed VS2015 update 1 is out. Though there's nothing about PS in the release notes, I'll install and see if they sneaked in a fix..

Comment: 5 months later, and this problem still exists... additionally, I am unable to utilize any visualizations for XML objects.